# Custom image gallery for android like Flickr

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-gallery

I am going to create a custom gallery for android like [Flickr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.flickr) or [Mobogenie market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobogenie.markets) app. This gallery has many images with difference view size like this:

[image]
[image]

I wonder is there any open source library can do this? I am starting with [this library](https://github.com/luminousman/MultipleImagePick) which uses custom `GridView` for multiple selection, but I don't know how to layout image view item with difference sizes to fit screen like images above.
Is there any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also look at Comcast's recently open-sourced "[FreeFlow](https://github.com/Comcast/FreeFlow)".

Comment: Thanks, look like it is what I want. I'll give it a try.